# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: flutter, object, dart, snapshot

Bantu saya untuk memecahkan masalah dibawah ini

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel{
  static const NUMBER = 'number';
  static const ID = 'id';

  String _number = '';
  String _id = '';

  String get number => _number;
  String get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    _number = snapshot.data()![NUMBER];
    _id = snapshot.data()![ID];
  }
}
```

**With the following errors**

> lib/models/user_model.dart:16:30: Error: The operator '[]' isn't
> defined for the class 'Object?'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   _number = snapshot.data()[NUMBER];
>   ^ lib/models/user_model.dart:17:26: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   _id = snapshot.data()[ID];

Comment: could you provide DocumentSnapshot model?

Comment: `snapshot.data!.data()[NUMBER]` _ number replace with this and as well as id too

Comment: First of all, how are you accessing NUMBER directly. It's a static const, it should be UserModel.NUMBER right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the recent version of cloud firestore DocumentSnapshot is a generic type so you need to pass a type argument along with it.
Example -**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel{
  static const NUMBER = 'number';
  static const ID = 'id';

  String _number = '';
  String _id = '';

  String get number => _number;
  String get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> snapshot){
    _number = snapshot.data()![NUMBER];
    _id = snapshot.data()![ID];
  }
}
```